# Should I use different user names for different databases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, cpanel

The webhost I am using limits max_user_connections (for MySQL access) to 10.  I understand this to mean maximum simultaneous database queries.  I have a small application which accesses several databases and has 80 users.  With this setup my users have never exceeded the limit.

I am slowly adding customers and have added several more databases (each of my customer accounts has 1 database and 20-50 users).  I now have created 10 databases, although only 5 are live.

As soon as I log on to control panel, all of my users get kicked off with a max_user_connections exceeded error.  I finally figured out that this was because I had 10 databases with the same user, I removed the user from 1 of the databases and the issue is resolved.  This tells me that by simply logging on to control panel all of my databases must be queried simultaneously (I suppose to access db information).  I would think my webhost would consider this an issue; just because I have 10 databases with the same user doesn't mean I plan on accessing them all simultaneously. However, they didn't seem that bothered by it.

My question: is it considered good practice to have one MySQL user accessing many databases or should I have one user per database?

Comment: Get a better host. That's an uncomfortably low limit.

Comment: I've actually been thinking about that for a while given that their helpdesk is pretty woeful on top of this (and other) issues.  I'm on their low-end plan, i.e. shared servers.  I'm probably going to upgrade to a dedicated server which increases the limit.  This will solve my problem but I'd still like to hear what folks have to say about my question.